# Vue Router moves to route but loads wrong component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have the following router config:

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'notselected',
      component: PackageUnselected
    },
    {
      path: '/package/:id',
      children: [
        { path: 'meta', name: 'packageMeta', component: ViewPackageMeta },
        { path: 'readme', name: 'packageReadme', component: PackageReadme },
        { path: 'docs', name: 'packageDocs', component: PackageDocs },
        {
          path: 'playground',
          name: 'packagePlayground',
          component: PackagePlayground
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      component: About
    },
    {
      path: '*',
      redirect: '/'
    }
  ]
});
```

And when I'm at the root route it correctly identifies the route name as `notselected`.  When I route to any of the "/package/[id]" routes though it continues to load the `PackageUnselected` component instead of the appropriate route (aka, `ViewPackageMeta`, `PackageDocs`, etc.).

Now at the point in the DOM where I want the route to insert the route's component I have the following template:

```
<v-tab-item v-for="item in tabs" :id="'tab-item-' + item" :key="item" exact>
  item: {{item}}
  <router-view :selectedPackage="selected"></router-view>
</v-tab-item>
```

And because I have installed `vuex-router-sync` it's easy to see the route state at any given time. So when clicking on the route that *should* load `PackageDocs`:

[image]

But the component view window of **vue-devtools** looks like this:

[image]

the highlighted area shows that NO component has been loaded into the tabs. I then tried adding a **component** to the definition of the parent route `/package/:id`:

```
{
  path: '/package/:id',
  component: Packages,
  children: [
    { path: 'meta', name: 'packageMeta', component: ViewPackageMeta },
    { path: 'readme', name: 'packageReadme', component: PackageReadme },
    { path: 'docs', name: 'packageDocs', component: PackageDocs },
    {
      path: 'playground',
      name: 'packagePlayground',
      component: PackagePlayground
    }
  ]
},
```

I then had to create the world simplest component for `Packages`:

```
<template>
  <view-router-view></view-router-view>
</template>
```

This results in the following:

[image]

Hmmm. Can't figure out what to do next. Anyone have any pointers?

Comment: Have you read over the documentation on [nested routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html)? Likely what you need is a single `<view-router>` outlet that displays the active tab, but the tabs loop is creating a separate outlet for each one. This reflects what you see in the dev tools.

Comment: Yeah I know I started with the default Vuetify way of using the component (which relies on v-model) and had planned on refactoring that later. I have refactored it now so that the VTabItem is removed and there is a single `<view-router>`. Still the overall problem is unchanged though.

Comment: I have gotten it to work but in an inelegant way ... I just created a number of root routes but I’d love to solve the problem in way more similar to how I started.

Comment: Are you familiar with [dynamic components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html)? I've found them to be, at least what I consider, a more elegant approach than having many routes.

Comment: Yeah I used them extensively in Ember and I remember I read about them in VueJS but I haven’t pulled that out of the toolkit yet. I’ll have a look, I can see how they might work better in many cases.

Comment: What is your full path/url ?

Comment: Can you share live demo of this. Add snippet if possible or any jsfiddle ?

Comment: I will but it may take a bit of time as I have gotten the router by taking the nested routes out and add them individually as root routes. I need to stabilize this release and I'll post onto code sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

> When I route to any of the "/package/[id]" routes though it continues
>   to load the PackageUnselected component instead of the appropriate
>   route (aka, ViewPackageMeta, PackageDocs, etc.).

That is the correct behavior of the vue-router.

Children can only be loaded when URL paths are:

- `/package/[id]/meta`
- `/package/[id]/readme`
- `/package/[id]/playground`
- `/package/[id]/docs`

Parent path may not have component defined if you have configured `redirect` option and your user, who opens `/package/[id]` will be redirected to your default path (could be anything).

Lets move to the next part of your question...

```
<v-tab-item v-for="item in tabs" :id="'tab-item-' + item" :key="item" exact>
  item: {{item}}
  <router-view :selectedPackage="selected"></router-view>
</v-tab-item>
```

You don't need to create here 4 different `<router-view>` tags, you just need one where all your children components will display html code.

```
<v-tab-item v-for="item in tabs" :id="'tab-item-' + item" :key="item" exact></v-tab-item>
<router-view></router-view>
```

Now you will have only one `router-view` and it's the `default` one. When user clicks on any of your tabs you just need to `this.$router.push` a new path on `@click`-event in `Packages` component. That's it.

I have created a [simple example (codepen)](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gqYbGR) to demonstrate how this task can be solved:

```js
Vue.use(VueRouter);

// Components
let MetaPackages = {
  mounted() { console.log('Mounted MetaPackages...'); },
  template: `<div>MetaPackages...</div>`,
};
let DocsPackages = {
  mounted() { console.log('Mounted DocsPackages...'); },
  template: `<div>DocsPackages...</div>`,
};
let ReadmePackages = {
  mounted() { console.log('Mounted ReadmePackages...'); },
  template: `<div>ReadmePackages...</div>`,
};
let Packages = {
  mounted() { console.log('Mounted Packages... ' + this.$route.path); },
  template: '<div>Packages (parent) screen...<br/><router-view></router-view></div>',
};

// Router
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'hash',
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/packages/:id",
      component: Packages,
      children: [
        {path:"meta", component: MetaPackages},
        {path:"docs", component: DocsPackages},
        {path:"readme", component: ReadmePackages}
      ]
    }
  ]
});

// Vue instance
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: {Packages, MetaPackages, DocsPackages, ReadmePackages}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-router/3.0.2/vue-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"> 
  <router-link to="/packages/100/meta">Meta</router-link>
  <router-link to="/packages/100/docs">Docs</router-link>
  <router-link to="/packages/100/readme">Readme</router-link>
  <hr/>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```